# Specifying One-to-one relationship foreign key in JPA

Tags: jpa

I am implementing REST API using Spring and JPA. Consider for example the following scenario where there are Project and Department entities where a Project belongs to a single Department. I would normally have a Department object referenced in Project Pojo, with a @OneToOne annotation.

When creating a Project through REST API (where a Department is already created), I am currently getting departmentID as an attribute from the user, loading Department object using the ID, associating it to the Project and then saving the Project instance using JPA. Is there a way to avoid this and directly save the Project by specifying department ID directly?

Answer (score 0):

Create two entity classes like

```
class Department{

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade =  CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = "department")
   Project project;
}

class Project{

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Still not very clear on the approach though. When creating a project, I'll only have department ID as input. So should I have two properties in Project Pojo - one for department ID and another for department instance?

Comment: Firstly you find department by ID then value of project and update save.